# jQuery/Css Use z-index and relative position for a centered button?

Tags: jquery, css, position, z-index

I have a button which is positioned in the center of another div (container).
When the button is clicked, some other divs show up in this container as well. 
Actually they're there but with css dipslay: none, and shown with jQuery.

But when you click to show these divs, the button gets knocked out of the div. I understand why, but I thought I could use z-index to keep the button in place?

My question to you is, how can I keep the button in place without having to use position absolute?

*the reason I don't want to use position absolute is because I want to keep it responsive. if I use absolute for the button, everything is responsive except the button.
If this is nonsense, please let me know also!*

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yRGrL/)

**CSS**

```
#button {
    height:40px;
    width:100px;
    margin: -20px -50px;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index: 30;
}
#container {
    z-index: 2;
    height: 424px;
    width: 424px;
    background: black;
}
div.square {
    background: gray;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" value="show" id="button"></input>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#button').bind('click', function () {

    $('.square').show();

});
```

Comment: why not use position absolute?

Comment: the reason I don't want to use position absolute is because I want to keep it responsive. if I use absolute for the button, everything is responsive except the button

Comment: The z-index property is for altering the stacking order when elements overlap.  It isn't going to fix the fact that your button is being pushed outside of the container.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it without absolute positioning if you set the relative position of the button to -105px

```
$('#button').bind('click', function () {

    $('.square').show();
    $(this).css('left', '-105px');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/yRGrL/5/

Comment: and `z-index` to `-1` maybe?

Comment: You should use $(this) instead of $('#button') in click handler callback function

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently unresponsive about an absolute positioned element.  Absolute positioning becomes a problem when an element ends up outside of the viewport.  Using absolute positioning here makes your demo no less responsive than when it started because the absolute positioning is relative to the `#container` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/yRGrL/4/

```
#button {
    height:40px;
    width:100px;
    margin: -20px -50px;
    position: absolute; /* modified */
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index: 30;
}
#container {
    z-index: 2;
    height: 424px;
    width: 424px;
    background: black;
    position: relative; /* added */
}
div.square {
    background: gray;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```